# Change selection-color of WPF ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a ListView containing some ListViewItems. By default, selecting items makes their background to some deep blue. I would like to apply a style such that selecting an item does not change its look.

In my xaml I already achieved this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
   <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
   </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately, this does not do the trick. It just simply makes the selection white instead of blue.

Does anyone have an idea?

Best wishes,
Christian

**EDIT:**
Sample Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>                      
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>



<ListView x:Name="lvTestRun" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestRunData}" Margin="177,26,8,53.277" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Duration"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Start Time"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="End Time"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In order to reproduce this, you may have to set the background color of a single ListViewItem to something like green or red.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by white instead of blue. When a ListViewItem is selected the foreground and background is changed by a trigger. To change the foreground of a ListViewItem you can use this

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Foreground for Selected ListViewItem -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
                                 Color="Black"/>
                <!-- Background for Selected ListViewItem -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                 Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListView>
```

**Update**

Try this for re-templating. I removed all triggers for selected

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF1FBFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD5F1FE" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"   
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"   
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Border Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11" />
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Rectangle Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#75FFFFFF" />
                                    <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"   
                                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"   
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemHoverFill}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCCF0FF" />
                                <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedFill}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
                                <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#80FFFFFF" />
                                <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Fill" Value="#40FFFFFF" />
                            </Trigger>-->
                            <!--<MultiTrigger> 
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions> 
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" /> 
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" /> 
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions> 
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedInactiveFill}" /> 
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFCFCF" /> 
            </MultiTrigger>-->
                            <!--<MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedHoverFill}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
                            </MultiTrigger>-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried your code and it gives me almost what I want. However: Before clicking the items they already have a background color. Some of them are green, some are red, some yellow and some are orange. Now when I select a number of them, they all get white. White because of the "Transparent" in your code. If I change Transparent to Black, they all get black. What I would like to achieve is that they stay the same color as they were before. Is that possible? As in to tell the style resource that upon selection it should NOT change the "HighlightBurshKey"?

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at this: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ListBoxSelectionBackground.html or http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.be/2009/08/how-to-set-wpf-listview-selected-item.html -the same principle applies for the ListView control.

For example, the following triggers based code should do the trick and imitate no change of colour when the selection is changed.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true" >
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="YourForegroundColour" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="YourBackgroundColour" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is define that color in the listview's resource collection. Then for each item I can define a template with the colors I like and when I select I don't get the blue.

I do think you should have some sort of indication that an item is selected though.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by indication that an item is selected? What I want is that there is no visual difference between a selected item and a non-selected. I know this sounds strange, but the reason I want this is because in the ListView I have a column named "checked" that contains a checkbox and this checkbox is my indication for a selected row.

Answer (score 0):

For also disabling inactive style,

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```