# WPF ListView: Set the Background color for specific items when Focusable is set to false

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Basically, I have a ListView with two conditions:

- Don't let the user select any items (for usability reason)
- Display rows with a special background color if they fulfill a certain condition

Doing either of the points is easy, but I don't manage to do both at the same time. An example to make explanations easier:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    [... the rest ...]
</ListView>
```

If I remove the ListView.ItemContainerStyle part, the background colors are drawn correctly. But when Focusable is set to false, setting the Background to LightGray has no effect.

Is there a way to do both at the same time?

Comment: might be easier to use a item template like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6174312/1328536

Comment: And item template might be a workaround, yes. Thank you for the hint. Still, I'm hoping to get a pointer to some stupid thinking error of mine :). I mean, the default behaviour exactly is what I need: I just want to list each item of a collection and show different properties in columns. It did so very well up to now. Not sure how easy it is to make such a generic item template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code you are effectively setting the style twice, so the second style declaration is being ignored.  Get rid of the ItemContainerStyle and move your Focusable property into the second style as below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
[... the rest ...]
</ListView>
```

Comment: Oh. That was the kind of pointer to some stupid thinking error of mine I was hoping for ;). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need one more trigger to address "if selected" appearance. Something like that:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="place a color you want">
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Also, you may find this discussion usefull too: [Change selection-color of WPF ListViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246795/change-selection-color-of-wpf-listviewitem)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure whether this really is an answer to my question. Because it is not about changing the color of a selected ListView item but about changing the color of an _unselectable_ ListVIew item :).

Comment: Another option: what if you try <ItemsControl/> instead of <ListView/>? Beware it lacks of many useful features, however. For example, you have to wrap it into <ScrollViewer/> if need to scroll.

Comment: I think that the disadvantages of an ItemsControl are too big - I would rather remove the condition that no iteams may be selectable than not using a ListView. But thank you for your answers - they also helped for possible other cases.