# How can I override the ContentTemplate of a ListView to add a vertical separator?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, controltemplate

I'm looking to modify a WPF ListView so that the items are rendered horizontally, and there is a separator between the first item and all subsequent items. Something like this: [image: Horizontal list with first item separated]

I've got the horizontal bit, but I'm stuck with the separator. I tried using a DataTemplate, but this incorporates the separator into the actual item which means it gets highlighted when I hover (note I'm using Caliburn, but I don't think it will affect the question much):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <ListView Name="Items" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
                    <Border Name="Separator" Width="2" Margin="5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsFirst, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

The Items are very basic views with this border:

```
<Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
```

How it looks with DataTemplate:

[image: Incorrectly highlighting the selector]

After spending the morning reading up on templates, I decided that a ControlTemplate was the solution which after a struggle gave me this code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                        <Border Name="Separator" Width="2" Margin="5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsFirst, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="Items">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

This looks almost identical, but now I'm unable to highlight items for some reason. I thought maybe I had overridden the triggers as well, and tried adding in a ControlTemplate.Triggers entry based on this answer: [Change selection-color of WPF ListViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246795/change-selection-color-of-wpf-listviewitem) to bring back highlighting behaviour, but without success.

How can I get the result I'm looking for, and is the ControlTemplate the right place to be making this change?

EDIT: Ideally I'm looking for a solution using just xaml.

Comment: That separator is rather a part of container for items than `ListViewItem` itself. You are using horizontal `StackPanel` now, try to write own `HorizontalPanelWithSeparator`.

Comment: I will give it a go, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick attempt of custom panel with separator

```
public class MyPanel : StackPanel
{
    static MyPanel()
    {
        OrientationProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal));
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);
        if (Children.Count >= 2)
        {
            var child = Children[0] as FrameworkElement;
            if (child != null)
                dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2), new Point(child.ActualWidth + 2, 5), new Point(child.ActualWidth + 2, ActualHeight - 5));
        }
    }
}
```

use it like this

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <local:MyPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Currently panel doesn't arrange/measure children to allocate space for separator, you will have to ensure there is a margin between them.

Comment: Thanks for this, with a little bit of fiddling with the margins I was able to produce the behaviour I wanted. Ideally I'm looking for a xaml-only solution so I'm going to leave the question open and keep experimenting but if nothing else comes in then I'll accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve this.

If you can show your view model I can help you more in a concrete manner. But your data template for first item would be different from the rest and contain the separator you want. Rest of the items can use the normal template.

As an alternate, databind the visibility property to a Boolean field in your view model which is only true for first item.

Comment: Hi Tanveer, thanks for your answer, unfortunately visibility is not my problem. I'm struggling to get the separator to not be included within the highlight box when I hover the mouse over the first item (as can be seen in my second picture). As for the ViewModels, the `ItemViewModel` simply has a `boolean IsFirst` property, and the `ItemsViewModel` simply contains a `List<ItemViewModel>` property which I initialise in the constructor with 3 items (passing true to the first and false to the second two).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out how to re-add the triggers (which I confirmed were missing using my new favourite WPF tool [WPF Inspector](https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/)). Once that was done the final problem was that the separator was also triggering a mouse over event for the first element which I fixed by targeting the inner border:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border x:Name="ItemBorder" Padding="2">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Name="Separator" Width="2" Margin="5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsFirst, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="Border.Background" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ItemBorder, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="Border.Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="Items">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

For some unknown reason the ItemBorder element needs a padding of 2 otherwise the border cannot be seen.