# Customize Listview Selected item and hover item background based on property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using a listview to display the status of an observable list of objects customizing the background according to a property of the object.
I managed to customize the background of a listview item with triggers but once I select a item or move the cursor in it it's gone.
What I'd like to do is to change the color once I select an item but it should be dependent on a property value too like the background is with triggers.
Here's my current status:

```
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvDataBinding" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Stato}" Value="Caricato">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF82CA9D" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Stato}" Value="Errore">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF7977A" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Stato}" Value="InCoda">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF79A" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="Nome: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="ID tessera: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <TextBlock Text="Stato: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatoString}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="Data: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="N. Documento: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="Cassa: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246795/change-selection-color-of-wpf-listviewitem

Comment: I found a couple of links like that but all use a predefined background and never something customizable according to a property value

Comment: You should see the __Update__ part of the linked accepted answer. I don't think you will get away without redefining the template.

Comment: so I'll have to define every possible combination (selected value1, notselected value1,selected value2, notselected value2 etc etc)?

Comment: Combinations aside, you need to understand that your background setting will basically be ignored for selected / hovered items, because the control template is designed to set different colors in this case. Once you have a solution where you can specify *some* background that works even when selected, you can start worrying about the different combinations.